# How to broadcast CEP patterns and iterate through multiple patterns in CEP?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am trying to apply a list of patterns on Patternstream in CEP i tried something attaching code below i am new to Flink, i am not sure whether this is a stupid approach or correct approach, i am not sure whether i can use datastream inside a processFunction in KeyedBroadCastFunction or not

```
   public static final MapStateDescriptor<String, String> patternDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<String,
            String>("CEPPatternList", BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);
  
  StreamExecutionEnvironment env = env.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
 
 DataStream<JSONObject> source =
                env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList(event, event2, event3));//KafkaSource


        DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> eventDataStream =
                source.map(new JSONObjectToTuple2());

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> eventStream = eventDataStream.keyBy(0);


        DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> patternStream =
                env.fromElements(pattern).flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String,
                        String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) throws Exception {
                        out.collect(new Tuple2<>("PATTERN_1", value));
                    }
                });




        BroadcastStream<Tuple2<String, String>> broadcastStream =
                patternStream.broadcast(patternDescriptor);


        DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> output =
                eventStream.connect(broadcastStream).process(new KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<String,
                        JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, JSONObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void processElement(Tuple2<String, JSONObject> value, ReadOnlyContext ctx,
                                               Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> out) throws Exception {

                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> patterns :
                                ctx.getBroadcastState(patternRuleDescriptor).immutableEntries()) {

                            String patternValue = patterns.getValue();

                            DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> eventStream =
                                    env.fromElements(value);

 
                            PatternStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> patternStream =
                                    cepPatternMatching.compile(patternValue,
                                            eventStream);

                            OutputTag<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> timedout = new OutputTag<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>>(
                                    "timedout") {
                            };

                            SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> result = patternStream.flatSelect(
                                    timedout,
                                    new EventTimeOut(),
                                    new PatternFlatSelect()
                            );


                            result.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Object>() {
                                @Override
                                public void flatMap(Tuple2<String, JSONObject> value, Collector<Object> out) throws Exception {
                                    out.collect(value);
                                }
                            });


                            ctx.output(unMatched,value);

                       }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void processBroadcastElement(Tuple2<String, String> value, Context ctx,
                                                        Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> out) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Pattern Name: " + value.f0);
                        System.out.println("Pattern Condition: " + value.f1);
                        ctx.getBroadcastState(patternDescriptor).put(value.f0, value.f1);
                    }
                });
```

I am not sure this is correct approach or not, i am getting below error

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the StreamExecutionEnvironment is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1821)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.BroadcastConnectedStream.clean(BroadcastConnectedStream.java:249)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.BroadcastConnectedStream.process(BroadcastConnectedStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.BroadcastConnectedStream.process(BroadcastConnectedStream.java:139)
    at CEPPatternMatchingApp.main(CEPPatternMatchingApp.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment

    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:586)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:133)
    ... 7 more
```

I am not doing serialization any where in my code not sure why this error is coming i tried even implementing serializable interface but still getting error

Can some please help me is there way to broadcast CEP patterns and iterate one by one to apply on a datastream

Comment: Could you please share the full stacktrace? In general, Flink uses serialization to transfer user-code to the taskmanagers, so none of your user code should hold a reference to the outer class.

Comment: @ArvidHeise I am attaching error stacktrace in question

Comment: Oh jeez. I just saw that you are using `DataStream` in user code. That's not going to work at all. I'm also not sure if CEP can be used with pattern at runtime at all. I suspect that you need to fall back to `DataStream` and implement it yourself in a [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html). Note that if you know the patterns at the start of the application you can use CEP.